# Error instaliling sqlite3. Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Everytime I try to `install bundle` I receive this error and I dont know what to do, I just update rails to 3.2.0. Im already on Ubuntu and my sqlite3 version is 3.37.2

I have tryed to uninstall sqlite3 and gem sqlite3-rails and then reinstall them, but nothing has change.

````
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/computer/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.5.4/ext/sqlite3
/home/computer/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/bin/ruby -I /home/computer/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0 extconf.rb
Building sqlite3-ruby using packaged sqlite3.
Extracting sqlite-autoconf-3400000.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-linux-gnu/ports/sqlite3/3.40.0... OK
Running 'configure' for sqlite3 3.40.0... OK
Running 'compile' for sqlite3 3.40.0... OK
Running 'install' for sqlite3 3.40.0... OK
Activating sqlite3 3.40.0 (from /home/computer/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.5.4/ports/x86_64-linux-gnu/sqlite3/3.40.0)...

Could not configure the build properly (pkg_config). Please install either the `pkg-config` utility or the `pkg-config` rubygem.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/computer/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.2.0/sqlite3-1.5.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/computer/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.5.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/computer/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.2.0/sqlite3-1.5.4/gem_make.out```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by installing `pkg-config` and then `bundle install` worked.

Here are the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config
bundle install
```

Comment: it should be `bundle install` there's a minor typo